# Vue.js how can i add dynamic component to the dom

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

in my app i need to add components to the dom after fetching data from an api

i have a component called `Carousel` and a component called `Home`

so i don't know how many carousels i need in my `Home` component

the question is : how can i add components using for loop from inside `methods:{}`

**My Code :**

`Home.vue`

```
    <template>
  <div>
      <template
        v-for="widget in widgets"
        v-bind:is="Carousel">
        {{ widget }}
      </template>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Carousel from './widgets/Carousel.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Carousel
    },
    data() {
      return {
        page_content: [],
        widgets: [],

      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getHomeContent();
    },
    methods:
      {
        addWidget() {
          this.widgets.push('Carousel')
        },
        getHomeContent() {
          window.axios.get(window.main_urls["home-content"]).then(response => {
            this.page_content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            this.addWidget()
          });
        }
      }
  }
</script>
```

`Carousel.vue`

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div :class="this.type == 'full' ? '' : 'container'">
            Slider
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default
      {
        name:'Carousel',
        props:[
          'type',
          'showTitle',
          'dots',
          'controls',
          'data'
        ],
    methods:
          {
          }
      }
    </script>
```

How to create as much `carousels` is i need using loop

the above code just give me a string 'carousel'

i want the component to be rendered

Comment: What data you need to loop for adding the component?

Comment: @Rijosh json data from an api (containing images and text ...)

Comment: That will assign to `page_content` and you want to add component as many items present in the data, right?

Comment: @Rijosh yes,  page_content will had the data i need,then i need to loop throw it,for example if the data from api contains a [type:carousel] i need to add Carousel component to the dom and initialize it with it's ```props``` like images and text so on.any idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working example of dynamic components with properties

```
<div>
   <template v-for="item in widgets">
     <component :is="item.name" :name="item.name" v-if="item.name==='carousel'"></component>
   </template>
</div>
```

The data in widgets

```
widgets: [
   {name: 'carousel'},
   {name: 'carousel'},
   {name: 'test'},
   {name: 'carousel'},
]
```

then it will create three components.

I created a test component like this to check this

```
    components: {
        'carousel': {
            template: "<div>Dynamic component {{name}}</div>",
            props: ["name"]
        }
    },
```